# Ember.js - How can I bind a property of a model class to a controller?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, asynchronous, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to somehow bind a property of the following model to a controller so that when the model has completed its async call the length property of the model is set and the controller is then notified of the changed and can update the view.

```
App.Articles = Ember.Object.extend()

App.Articles.reopenClass
    store: {}
    lengths: 0

    findAll: ->
        arr = Ember.ArrayProxy.create()

        $.ajax
            url: 'http://ajaxcall.asp',
            dataType: 'json'
            context: @
            success: (response) ->
                Ember.set(App.Articles, 'lengths', response.store.length)

                response.store.forEach (news, i) =>
                    txt = '<p>' + news.fields[2].text.replace(/[\r\n]+(?=[^\r\n])/g,'</p><p>') + '</p>'
                    article = 
                        'id': i
                        'date': news.fields[1].date
                        'title': news.fields[0].text
                        'text': txt
                        'short': news.fields[2].text.substring(0, 120) + '...'

                    art = @findOne(article.id)
                    art.setProperties(article)
                    return

                values = (values for keys, values of @store)
                arr.set('content', values)

                callback = ->
                    $('.loader-container').removeClass('show')
                    $('#articles-scroll').css('height', $(window).height() - 55)

                    articles_scroll = new iScroll 'articles-scroll', 
                        vScroll: true, hScroll: false, vScrollbar: false
                    return

                setTimeout callback, 100
                return
        arr

    findOne: (id) ->
        art = @store[id]
        if not art
            art = App.Currencies.create
                id: id
            @store[id] = art
        art
```

So what I need to accomplish is to set the length of the data returned after the call is complete and listen for that change in the controller with something like this:

```
lengths: (->
    console.log 'test'
).property('App.Articles.lengths')
```

However, I'm not having luck with the code above and I'm not sure how to go about solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use that value in your template, simply use the controller's length property: `{{controller.length}}`.

If you want to observe the length property in the controller:

```
App.ArticlesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  lengthDidChange: function() {
    console.log("Length changed to: " + this.get('length'));
  }.observes('length')
});
```

Provided you set up the controller with the articles array in your route's `model` hook or somewhere else.

**UPDATE:**

If you want one-time notification, mix in `Ember.Evented` into the `ArrayProxy` you return from `findAll` (unneeded stuff omitted):

```
App.Articles.reopenClass
  ...
  findAll: ->
    arr = Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.Evented)

    $.ajax
      ...
      success: (response) ->
        ...
        arr.set('content', values)
        arr.trigger('didLoad')

App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.Articles.findAll()

  setupController: (controller, model)->
    model.one 'didLoad', ->
      console.log controller.get('lastObject`)
```

Comment: Gabor, Thanks for the response. I don't need to monitor each change - I just need to set a specific article after the call is complete. If I observe the length changing I'll be setting an article with each change when all I need is to set one when they've all loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain "I just need to set a specific article" a bit more?

Comment: Gabor - thanks for getting back to me. So the page is loading a list of articles on the left and I want to populate the right side with the details of one of the articles from the list when the page first loads. I want to use the last article from the incoming data (as that is the most recent article) The problem I'm having is that I need to wait for the data to be completely loaded before I know how many articles came in and can select the last one. But I can't figure out how to get the model to somehow notify the controller that the call is complete and that it now has x number of articles.

Comment: The controller's `lastObject` property will always represent the last element.

Comment: Gabor - but how do I wait until the model is completely populated before I get the lastObject? Is there a way I can the model to notify the controller that is has finished the ajax call?

Comment: Updated the answer with the one-time notification version.